# Determine the value of the monthly payment if the sum of $5000$ is paid in the last year

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

The company wishes to sell its car for $23000$ usd cash. A client who wants the car offers to make semi-annual payments with a rate of $11.5\%$ with semi-annual capitalization, the first at the end of the first semester and the last payment at the end of four and a half years, and one year later pay the sum of $5000$ usd. If the company accepts these conditions, calculate the value of the semester fee.

I have solved but I am not sure if the answer is correct or not.

My solution:

Principal $P=23000$

rate $=\frac{11.5}{100}=0.015$

Semi-annual rate $r=\frac{0.015}{2}=0.0575$

last year's payment $f=5000$

Considering that four and a half years is equivalent to $10$ semesters then the total of semsters $n=10$

Then,

$$P=f+\text{semester fee}\,\sum_{k=1}^n(1+r)^{-k}.$$

So we have to

$$\text{semester fee}= \frac{P-f}{\sum_{k=1}^n(1+r)^{-k}}=\frac{23000-5000}{\sum_{k=1}^{10}(1+0.0575)^{-k}}=1038.88.$$

Comment: You have to discount $f$ as well since it's paid one year later.

Comment: Isn't $n=9$ (4.5 years) $+2$ (1 year)$=11$? With this I get a fee round about $\$3024.4$.